# AssertionError: The `.update()` method does not support writable nestedfields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a DeviceSerializer and DeviceGroupSerializer. DeviceSerializer has ios field as foreignkey and i have used save_ios, create and update function for it to save in database along with devices. But i need to add one more field of device_group and the relation of device_group and device is one to many(a device can be on one group but a group can have multiple devices).

Here is my serializer

```
class DeviceGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    class Meta:
        model = DeviceGroup
        fields = ('name',)

class DeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.UUIDField(source='token', format='hex', read_only=True)
    ios = DeviceIOSerializer(read_only=False, many=True, required=False)
    device_group = DeviceGroupSerializer(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'ios', 'device_group')

    def save_ios(self, device, ios):
        for io in ios:
            token = io.pop('token', None)
            if token is None:
                DeviceIO.objects.create(device=device, **io)
            else:
                DeviceIO.objects.filter(token=token, device=device).update(**io)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        ios = validated_data.pop('ios',[])
        instance = super(DeviceSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
        if len(ios):
            self.save_ios(instance, ios)
        return instance

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ios = validated_data.pop('ios',[])
        instance = super(DeviceSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        if len(ios):
            self.save_ios(instance, ios)

        return instance
```

When i try to create a new group, i get following error

> AssertionError: The `.update()` method does not support writable
>
> nestedfields by default. Write an explicit `.update()` method for
>
> serializer `device_api.serializers.DeviceSerializer`, or set
>
> `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields.

When i add `read_only=True`, there will be no error but the created group is not shown in device.

Comment: Is nestedfields a typo or is that an external dependency ?